# Laravel resource controller ajax call

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-4

Using Laravel 4.2, I have a resource controller setup like this:

```
Route::resource('faq', 'ProductFaqController');
```

When I hit the `/faq` URL on my server, the controller's `index()` method correctly loads.

In a js file, I would like to make an ajax call to one of the other actions for this resource controller, for example, the `store` action. Therefore, I do something like this:

```
 $.ajax({
    url:'store',
    dataType:'json',
    success:function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

The problem I'm having is that since the URL is `/faq` (without a trailing slash), the ajax call gets made to `/store`, instead of `/faq/store`.

Am I missing something here or do I need to prefix the url for all of my ajax calls with the route?

If I do need to add some sort of prefix, how do I get the appropriate prefix to use no matter resource controller is being called?

Comment: The answer you have accepted is modified with a comment please remove unmark it, as it is misleading somehow or if possible post your own answer or mark another answer correct, if it is available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run this from your command line, it will list all URL routes coupled together with the controller methods they are attached to:

```
$ php artisan routes     # Laravel 4
$ php artisan route:list # Laravel 5
```

Making a resource controller as you are creates 7 different routes.  None of those routes include `store` anywhere in the URL.  The `store` method exists on the controller, but responds to POST requests to the URL `/faq` (in your example)

**The solution to *this* problem**

Change your jQuery to POST instead of GET your data (which is default), and change your AJAX url to `'/faq'`.  It should then hit the correct route at that point.

As far as being able to hit a resource controller route without knowledge of the actual route, that on its face is impossible (think about trying to visit google.com without knowing that google.com exists).  I think however I understand what you're trying to do.  I'm assuming that the AJAX request is being sent off as a response to some user action, such as the clicking of a button.  You can attach a data attribute to that button with the value you're wanting so that you can make these requests in a sort-of resource agnostic way.

Something like this:

```
 <button class="test" data-resource="faq">Click me!</button>

 $('.test').on('click', function(e) {
    var resource = $(this).data("resource");

     $.ajax({
        url: '/' + resource,
        dataType:'json',
        type: 'post',
        success:function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: exactly, since Laravel provides you with RESTful routing when declaring routes with `Route::resources()` the `store()` action is executed with a POST to your resource's name (`faq`)

Comment: I think it should be `php artisan route:list` not `php artisan routes`

Comment: @rhand In Laravel 4 it was `php artisan routes` It looks like some of the Laravel 4 documentation has started to go missing (or it was never there), but I found a [source](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/5/listing-your-routes). I went ahead and added that to the answer though, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer doesn't answer my question, maybe because I asked it poorly. The point of my question is that I want to take advantage of Laravel's route naming functionality so that I don't have to hardcode the word "faq" into all of my JS files.  If the name of that controller changes, then I would need to make a change in every js file. After doing some more research, I have found this library to be what I was looking for.  I haven't tried implementing it yet, but it seems to accomplish what I need: https://github.com/fedeisas/laravel-js-routes.